# Working with Dropbox Sync API and Dropbox Standard API in iOS

Tags: objective-c, synchronization, dropbox-api

I need to work with both `DropboxSDK.framework` and `Dropbox.framework`

Is it a mistake and both have the same functionality?

If it is not, I need the functionality from both frameworks but there are some crashes in the building because of repeated declarations:

```
.../Dropbox.framework/Headers/DBAccountInfo.h:5:1: Duplicate interface definition for class 'DBAccountInfo'
```

..`./Dropbox.framework/Headers/DBError.h:32:3: Typedef redefinition with different types ('enum DBErrorCode' vs 'enum DBErrorCode')`

Comment: Both the frameworks have a couple or more headers with same names(DBAccount.h etc.) That's why crash occurs

Comment: For anyone also interested, see the thread here: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=97281

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102536/dropbox-core-and-sync-apis-together-in-ios-app