# Dropbox Core and Sync APIs together in iOS app

Tags: ios, synchronization, dropbox-api

I wanna use Dropbox's Core and Sync APIs together in an iOS app, I have started working on it and implemented core API successfully using framework **DropboxSDK.framework**, Now I started working on Sync API and added **Dropbox.framework** and I am getting:

**…../Dropbox.framework/Headers/DBAccountInfo.h:5:1: Duplicate interface definition for class 'DBAccountInfo'**

**…../Dropbox.framework/Headers/DBError.h:32:3: Typedef redefinition with different types ('enum DBErrorCode' vs 'enum DBErrorCode')**

I know this is happening because some of the header are same in both API framework I am using in this app. Is there any solution to make these two API work in same app.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: looks like this isn't really intended to be done, but it's possible with some work: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=97281

Comment: thanks for your response Greg, I will give it a try..

Comment: Hi @user2029544 did you find the solution for this problem?

Comment: Pls let us know for this solution

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, so I've made a framework that makes this a bit easier.

https://github.com/skela/dbcore